# Is there any difference between '(let (var) ...)' and '(let ((var nil)) ...)'?

Tags: let-binding

I've seen both  `(let (var) ...)` and `(let ((var nil)) ...)` is there any difference between these statements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation for `let` says:

```
Each element of VARLIST is a symbol (which is bound to nil)
or a list (SYMBOL VALUEFORM) (which binds SYMBOL to the value of VALUEFORM).
```

The `let (var)` variant matches the first line — `var` is a symbol, bound to nil. The `let ((var nil))` variant matches the second line — `(var nil)` where `var` is the symbol and the initial value is nil.

They do the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 13):

@amitp provided the answer. They do have the same behavior.

---

However, IMO they can indicate something slightly different to a human reader of the code -- at least according to an informal convention.  That is, they can convey a different connotation.

I use `(let (foo) ...)` only when the initial value is intentionally set in the `let` body, e.g., in a conditional way.  It tells me, as a (later) reader of my own code, that an initial value of `nil`, which is what it provides, isn't used - makes no difference.

I use `let ((foo  nil)) ...)` to indicate that the `nil` binding matters -- it really is an intentional initialization. I do it to make the value more obvious.

I do the latter also in the case of binding a global variable for which I know that a `nil` value has a particular behavior.  Using that form, with the explicit `nil`, points out to me clearly that I'm imposing that `nil` behavior there.  IOW, it just makes the binding more obvious.